# How do you use a FOR loop in a list to add items from a JSON file? Discord.py

Tags: python, json, for-loop, discord, discord.py

## Let me explain...

Take a look at this JSON file:

```
{
    "Gaming":"Become an Epic Gamer Dude!",
    "Reaction":"React to Trending Topics!",
    "Vlogging":"Share Events of Your Life!",
    "Technology":"Show us Some Geek Stuff!",
    "Business":"How to make money online?",
    "Music":"Craft For us Some Beats!",
    "Fashion":"Looking Good in That Outfit!"
}
```

These are some social media niches that I have in a JSON file + a sentence about each. I am not having any issues with this, instead, take a look at this select menu (Py-Cord or discord.py):

```
with open('niches.json', 'r') as f:
    niches = json.load(f)

niche_menu = Select(placeholder="What Type of Influencer are you?", options=[
    for niche in niches:
        discord.SelectOption(label=(niche).upper(), emoji="", description=f"Select this to be a {niche}!")
        ])
```

What i am trying to do this use a for loop that takes the niches from the json file and adds a select option to the menu labelled with that niche. But I get a SYNTAX ERROR labeling the 'for' statement. So how do I do this correctly? Can we use a for loop inside a list to add items? Would appreciate some help, Thanks -

Error:

```
  File "C:\Users\dado\Saved Games\Enflooencer\main.py", line 254
    for niche in niches:
    ^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 343ms]
```

Comment: Could you provide the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

For loop is not possible to use in list syntax. Did you mean to use list comprehension?

Either move loop outside to generate a list:

```py
options = []
for niche in niches:
    options.append(discord.SelectOption(label=(niche).upper(), emoji="", description=f"Select this to be a {niche}!"))

niche_menu = Select(placeholder="What Type of Influencer are you?", options=options)
```

Or fix it to be a proper list comprehension:

```py
niche_menu = Select(placeholder="What Type of Influencer are you?", options=[discord.SelectOption(label=(niche).upper(), emoji="", description=f"Select this to be a {niche}!") for niche in niches])
```

---

Simpler explanation what you did:

You did `[for x in iterable: f(x)]`

Non-comprehension solution is:

```py
res = []
for x in iterable:
    res.append(f(x))
```

List comprehension syntax is `[f(x) for x in iterable]`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a `for` loop inside a `list` like this. You can use a `list` comprehension which does the same thing though:

```
niche_menu = Select(
    placeholder="What Type of Influencer are you?", options=[discord.SelectOption(label=(niche).upper(
    ), emoji="", description=f"Select this to be a {niche}!") for niche in niches]
)
```

This is not the cleanest method, I recommend just assigning it to a variable before passing as an argument.

```
x = [discord.SelectOption(label=(niche).upper(
), emoji="", description=f"Select this to be a {niche}!") for niche in niches]

niche_menu = Select(
    placeholder="What Type of Influencer are you?", options=x)
```